# Status 133 при подключении по BLE

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, samsung

Занимаюсь разработкой под android. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Пытаюсь подключиться к девайсу по BLE, но в ответ получаю статус 133 и коннект рвется. как решить эту проблему

```
    public class BLE {
    public BluetoothDevice mDevice;
    private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
    Context context;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothDevice device;


    public BLE(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        final BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        this.device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("80:EA:CA:80:00:01");
    }

    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                Log.d("MY_TAG", "Устройство подключено");
                gatt.discoverServices();


            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                Log.d("MY_TAG", "Устройство не подключено...");
            }
        }
    };


    public boolean connectDevice() {
        Log.d("MY_MET", "connectDevice()");
        if (device == null) {
            return false;
        }
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
         public void run() {
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(context, false, mGattCallback);

           }
        }).start();
        return true;
    }
}



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BLE ble;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ble =  new BLE(this);
    }

    public void connect(View view)
    {
        ble.connectDevice();
    }

}
```

судя по логам соединение рвется сразу после получения статуса 133. Что за сатутс я так и не понял.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На англоязычных форумах рекомендуют делать так:

```
mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
mBluetoothGatt.close();
```

Это тоже не помогло.
P.S. использую Samsung Galaxy S5